# when statements should not include jinja2 templating

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I need an if condition in when statement. How can I do that?

Now it looks like this:

```
when: {% if routes is defined %}'celery' is in routes{% else %}inventory_hostname in groups['celery']{% endif %} and deploy_state.colors.celery is defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the equivalent might be

```
when: (((routes is defined) and ('celery' is in routes)) or
       (inventory_hostname in groups['celery'])) and
       (deploy_state.colors.celery is defined)
```

Comment: Thank you. It was my previusly variant=))